# How to restore a stolen iPhone 5 after being found?

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 5 was stolen and I erased and removed it via iCloud.

After three days I found it and want to active it again.

What is the procedure for recovering the content and activating it again?

Comment: If you erased it via iCloud, it would no longer be tied to any account & you should be able to set it up as new

Comment: The only way to recover the content would be restore from a backup. When you start to set it up, it will ask if you want to restore from an iCloud or iTunes backup. Follow the on-screen instructions to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

If you backed up your iPhone using iTunes (stored on your computer) or iCloud (stored in iCloud), restore from backup.

When your iPhone has sufficient charge to turn on, you probably see the "Hello" screen.  The following Apple Support article describes how to restore your iPhone from iTunes backup or iCloud backup:    https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204686